# Why is VS trying to download symbols for local assemblies from MS?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols

If I uncheck 'Enable Just My Code', for some reason Visual studio keeps trying to download symbols for my assemblies from MS. Assemblies that are in the solution I'm running!

Any ideas?